# Can I expect that a stream is closed by the garbage Collector?

Tags: .net, vb.net, stream

i have a class like a stream with a "Close" function. The instance of this class is stored in a Field/Attribute. Sometimes I have to replace this instance with a fresh one. Unfortunally I can't find out if someone still uses the old instance of the Object.(Many Many functions use this field with Multithreading). So I can just overwrite the field without closing the class. Can I expect that the GC removes the not closed object oder can I close it in the dispose function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class should be [implementing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737.aspx) [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) and any user of it should be instantiating it in a [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

This will ensure correct closing/disposal.

The GC will not close/dispose of classes that are still referenced, so it really depends on the code you have written and how the class is being used.

Comment: There is no reason the OP's class can not also expose Close() just as the Stream class does which will ultimately call Dispose on the needed underlying objects

Comment: @Aaron - I agree it _can_ and probably _should_ do that, and that the `dispose` implementation should ensure closing. But relying on the users of your code to do the right thing leads to interesting bugs.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's what the dispose pattern requires.  Aside from having the GC track unmanaged resources other than memory, there is no way to guarantee unmanaged resources get cleaned except to have the user of the code take special steps (such as the `using` statement) to guarantee clean up.

Answer (score 1):

You not just *can* close it with the dispose method, but you **have** to close it, as a stream most like contains unmanaged resources, which the garbage collector can't take care of. Always `Dispose` classes implementing `IDisposable` if you are done using them.

If you use classes implementing `IDisposable` in a class, your class should implement the interface as well.

Answer (score 1):

`FileStream` et al. do have a Finalize() method, which just calls `Dispose()`.  While it's true that this will guarantee that the handles get closed eventually, it's not deterministic.  If you can manually close the streams yourself, that is the highly preferred method.  The `Finalize()` method is only there in case somehow the stream doesn't get closed manually (usually due to a bug in your logic).

As it happens, even the `Finalize()` method isn't 100% guaranteed to be called.  However, once your program exits, all handles will be closed by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

If your class has a finalizer, then yes. But, given your description, that's not the point.

Most likely, you want the class to implement `IDisposable`, so you can release unmanaged resources (or owned disposable instances) at the earliest time possible.

But there seem to be bigger design issues. Given that you have control over the field, you should *know* when it's safe to create a new instance and/or when to dispose of it. Apparently you have some shared instance across threads, without something that has clear ownership of that instance. Without code, and more detailed description, it's possible I'm wrong, but it sounds like an accident waiting to happen.